# List Comprehension Format for Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-science

I have a dictionary that has three categories for my customers, and there are multiple customers under each category:

```
ddd = {'category 1:': 
         {'A': 50.5,
          'B': 28.9,
          'C': 46.3,
          'D': 513.8},
       'category 2:': {'E': 20.5, 'C': 48.1},
       'category 3:': {'D': 28.2, 'F': 68.3}}
```

The number in each sub-dictionary represents the dollar amount they paid. Therefore, I want to convert all the number into string dollar amount format with two decimal places like 'A': 50.5 -> 'A': '$50.50'. The ideal output will be:

`{'category 1:': {'A': '$50.50', 'B': '$28.90', 'C': '$46.30', 'D': '$513.80'}, 'category 2:': {'E': '$20.50', 'C': '$48.10'}, 'category 3:': {'D': '$28.20', 'F': '$68.30'}}`

Here is my solution to this:

```
for a,b in ddd.items():
    for i,j in b.items():
        b[i] = "$" + "{0:,.2f}".format(j)
```

This will work, but I want to learn if it is possible to write the above nested for loop into a format similar to a one-liner list comprehension format.
I tried

```
{a:b for i,("$" + "{0:,.2f}".format(j)) in b.items() for a,b in ddd.items()}
```

but this doesn't seem work. Thank you in advance!

Writing codes in a simplified format.

Comment: I named my original dictionary as 'ddd' at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
ddd = {k: {ik: "$" + "{0:,.2f}".format(v) for ik, v in v.items()} for k, v in ddd.items()}
```

Comment: Thank you! this seems work. I just realize that I can still repeatedly use the same variable name k and v like {k: {k: "$" + "{0:,.2f}".format(v) for k, v in v.items()} for k, v in ddd.items()} and this is still working. wow